# After X server update 1.18.4 `su -- pi -c "startx" &` not working anymore

Tags: debian, apt, raspberry-pi, raspbian, x-server

My raspberry pi (Jessie) updated xserver-xorg-core to 1.18.4 from 1.17.2

Now `su -- pi -c "startx" &` in `/etc/rc.local` doesn't work anymore.

`Cannot open virtual console 2`

Update:

```
Start-Date: 2016-12-09  20:17:57
Commandline: apt full-upgrade -y
Install: libpam-systemd:armhf (215-17+deb8u5, automatic), libllvm3.9:armhf (3.9-4, automatic)
Upgrade: xserver-xorg-input-synaptics:armhf (1.8.2-1~bpo8+1, 1.8.3-2)
raspberrypi-sys-mods:armhf (20161205, 20161208+1)
libdrm-freedreno1:armhf (2.4.65-3~bpo8+1, 2.4.71-1+rpi1)
libglapi-mesa:armhf (11.1.0-1+rpi1, 13.0.0-1+rpi1)
libwayland-client0:armhf (1.6.0-2, 1.11.0-2)
xserver-xorg-core:armhf (1.17.2-1+rpi1, 1.18.4-2+rpi1)
libegl1-mesa:armhf (11.1.0-1+rpi1, 13.0.0-1+rpi1)
libgbm1:armhf (11.1.0-1+rpi1, 13.0.0-1+rpi1)
libdrm-radeon1:armhf (2.4.65-3~bpo8+1, 2.4.71-1+rpi1)
libxfont1:armhf (1.5.1-1, 1.5.2-1)
xserver-common:armhf (1.17.2-1+rpi1, 1.18.4-2+rpi1)
libdrm2:armhf (2.4.65-3~bpo8+1, 2.4.71-1+rpi1)
libdrm-nouveau2:armhf (2.4.65-3~bpo8+1, 2.4.71-1+rpi1)
raspi-config:armhf (20161114, 20161207)
libgl1-mesa-dri:armhf (11.1.0-1+rpi1, 13.0.0-1+rpi1)
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev:armhf (0.4.4-1+rpi1, 0.4.4-1+rpi2)
libdrm-amdgpu1:armhf (2.4.65-3~bpo8+1, 2.4.71-1+rpi1)
xserver-xorg-input-evdev:armhf (2.9.2-1~bpo8+1, 2.10.3-1)
xserver-xorg:armhf (7.7+7+b1, 7.7+16)
libgl1-mesa-glx:armhf (11.1.0-1+rpi1, 13.0.0-1+rpi1)
Remove: xserver-xorg-input-wacom:armhf (0.26.0+20140918-1)
End-Date: 2016-12-09  20:18:29
```

Full `/etc/rc.local`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

# Wait for the TV-screen to be turned on...
while ! $( tvservice --dumpedid /tmp/edid | fgrep -qv 'Nothing written!' ); do
        bHadToWaitForScreen=true;
        printf "===> Screen is not connected, off or in an unknown mode, waiting for it to become available...\n"
        sleep 10;
done;

printf "===> Screen is on, extracting preferred mode...\n"
_DEPTH=32;
eval $( edidparser /tmp/edid | fgrep 'preferred mode' | tail -1 | sed -Ene 's/^.+(DMT|CEA) \(([0-9]+)\) ([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)[pi]? @.+/_GROUP=\1;_MODE=\2;_XRES=\3;_YRES=\4;/p' );

printf "===> Resetting screen to preferred mode: %s-%d (%dx%dx%d)...\n" $_GROUP $_MODE $_XRES $_YRES $_DEPTH
tvservice --explicit="$_GROUP $_MODE"
sleep 1;

printf "===> Resetting frame-buffer to %dx%dx%d...\n" $_XRES $_YRES $_DEPTH
fbset --all --geometry $_XRES $_YRES $_XRES $_YRES $_DEPTH -left 0 -right 0 -upper 0 -lower 0;
sleep 1;

if [ -f /boot/xinitrc ]; then
        ln -fs /boot/xinitrc /home/pi/.xinitrc;
        su -- pi -c "startx" &
        bash /home/pi/.xinitrc;
fi

exit 0
```

Full `/boot/xinitrc`:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do

        # Clean up previously running apps, gracefully at first then harshly
        killall -TERM chromium 2>/dev/null;
        killall -TERM matchbox-window-manager 2>/dev/null;
        sleep 2;
        killall -9 chromium 2>/dev/null;
        killall -9 matchbox-window-manager 2>/dev/null;

        # Clean out existing profile information
        rm -rf /home/pi/.cache;
        rm -rf /home/pi/.config;
        rm -rf /home/pi/.pki;

        # Generate the bare minimum to keep Chromium happy!
        mkdir -p /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default
        sqlite3 /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Web\ Data "CREATE TABLE meta(key LONGVARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, value LONGVARCHAR); INSERT INTO meta VALUES('version','46'); CREATE TABLE keywords (foo INTEGER);";

        # Disable DPMS / Screen blanking
        xset -dpms
        xset s off

        # Reset the framebuffer's colour-depth
        fbset -depth $( cat /sys/module/*fb*/parameters/fbdepth );

        # Hide the cursor (move it to the bottom-right, comment out if you want mouse interaction)
        xwit -root -warp $( cat /sys/module/*fb*/parameters/fbwidth ) $( cat /sys/module/*fb*/parameters/fbheight )

        # Start the window manager (remove "-use_cursor no" if you actually want mouse interaction)
        matchbox-window-manager -use_titlebar no -use_cursor no &

        # Start the browser (See http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)
        chromium-browser --app=http://127.0.0.1/status

done;
```

What shall I do to make this work again?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You now (since version 2:1.17.2-2) NEED to have the X server running on the same VT as the one you have a session opened. X server tries to start without root rights (it uses `logind` to achieve this) but in counterpart, it cannot start on an arbitrary VT.

A quick fix might be to install the `xserver-xorg-legacy` package, this will allow the X server to start as root as before.

BTW why are you using `su --` instead of `su -`, aren't you trying start a login shell?